# Creating a game in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple game on a webpage.

The game should be like this:

1. The web page should display at random times images placed in random positions on the browser window.
2. Each image lasts on the browser window for a short period of time and then it disappears.
3. If the user clicks an image before it disappears, he/she gets a point.
4. The game ends when the user wins 10 points.

So far I managed to display all elements on a page at random positions, then delete them, and display them again.

Right now I am having problems with the count of each click.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    timeOut();
});

function timeOut() {

    setInterval(function () {
        deleteImages();
        createImages();
    }, 3000);

}

function createImages() {

    var myarray = ["img/Angel.gif", "img/Angry.gif", "img/BigSmile.gif",
        "img/Confused.gif", "img/Cool.gif", "img/Crying.gif",
        "img/Eyebrow.gif", "img/Goofy.gif", "img/Happy.gif"];
    var count = 0;
    var div;
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        var randPos = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
        this.img = document.createElement("img");
        div = document.createElement("div");

        $("div").attr("id", "div" + i);

        var randNew = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (5));
        var rand = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - count));
        this.img.src = myarray[rand];

        $('#div' + i).css("left", randPosition());
        $('#div' + i).css("right", randPosition());
        $('#div' + i).css("top", randPosition());
        $('#div' + i).css("bottom", randPosition());
        $('#div' + i).css("position", "relative");
        $('#div' + i).show();

        div.appendChild(this.img);

        $("body").prepend(div);
        myarray.splice(rand, 1);
        count++;
    }
    //setTimeout(function(){ jQuery("div").hide(); }, 3000);
}

function deleteImages() {
    $("div").remove();
}

function randPosition() {
    return 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
}

$(function () {
    $("div").click(function (e) {

        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

        alert("X: " + relativeX + "  Y: " + relativeY);

    });
});
```

css

```
.active-div{
    position:relative;
}

.menu-div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer to resolve the increment issue and also address the click events not being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter and increment when you click an image:

```
var count = 0;
count++;
```

Also you need to reapply the click event because you are recreating new elements instead of moving the already created ones:

Call this:

```
    $("div").click(function(e) {

      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
      var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

    });
```

after createImages function like so:

```js
var count = 0;
var holder;

$(document).ready(function(){
     timeOut();
});

function addOnClicks() {
  $("div").on('click',function(e) {

      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
      var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

      count++; 
      if(count >= 10)
      {
          deleteImages();
          clearInterval(holder);
          alert("Game Over");  
      }
  });
}

function timeOut(){

  holder = setInterval(function(){deleteImages();createImages();addOnClicks();    }, 3000); 

}
function createImages(){
var myarray=["img/Angel.gif","img/Angry.gif","img/BigSmile.gif",
"img/Confused.gif","img/Cool.gif","img/Crying.gif",
"img/Eyebrow.gif","img/Goofy.gif","img/Happy.gif"
];
var count=0;
 var div;
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {


    var randPos = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500); 
    this.img = document.createElement("img");
     div = document.createElement("div");

    $("div").attr("id","div"+i);
    var randNew = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (5)); 
    var rand = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (9-count)); 
    this.img.src = myarray[rand];

    $('#div'+i).css("left", randPosition());
    $('#div'+i).css("right",randPosition());
    $('#div'+i).css("top",randPosition());
    $('#div'+i).css("bottom",randPosition());
    $('#div'+i).css("position","relative");
    $('#div'+i).show();
     div.appendChild(this.img);
     $("body").prepend(div);
     myarray.splice(rand,1);
     count++;
}

//setTimeout(function(){ jQuery("div").hide(); }, 3000);

}

function deleteImages(){

$("div").remove();


}

function randPosition(){

    return 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
}
```

```css
.active-div{
position:relative;
}

.menu-div{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you displaying the position of the clicked element? I don't need that. I need a way to end the game when the count reached 10.

Comment: @dres That was your code.... lol.  I was telling you how to resolve the click issue because none of your images were clickable and also showing you how to implement a counter.  You had the alert in there I just didn't remove it..

Comment: @dres fixed, added count to end game.  Click images 10 times and the game ends.

Comment: @dres added functionality to not only say Gave Over but stop the Interval you have set, by holding the interval in `holder`

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to accept the answer in about 5 min, the system won't let me sooner. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Use an incremented variable like so:

```
$(function() {
    var click_count = 0;
    $("div").click(function(e) {
        click_count++;
    });
});
```